# PHPunit error Error: Call to undefined method SebastianBergmann\Environment\Runtime::discardsComments()

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to run `PHPunit` in my `ubuntu` machine. But when I run the command `phpunit`, it is showing the error

> Error: Call to undefined method SebastianBergmann\Environment\Runtime::discardsComments()

How can I avoid this and run the test? I am using `Drupal 7`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a globally installed PHPUnit. Especially not if you have a project-local PHPUnit that was installed using Composer. Use `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of `phpunit`.

Comment: I'm running vendor/bin/phpunit but still getting this same error. What does it mean? I also can't find any other installation of phpunit in my machine

Comment: Please ignore my question. I found that it was another version of phpunit getting autoloaded with a google/apiclient that was included in project and having a separate autoloader of its own. I was able to resolve it by loading google/apiclient also using same composer autoload.